# AIDL unable to find the definition of a Parcelable class

Tags: android, class, parcelable, aidl

I have the following project structure.

[image]

My `StockInfo.java` is perfectly fine.

### StockInfo.java (No error)

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.engine;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class StockInfo implements Parcelable {
    ...
    ...
```

### StockInfo.aidl (No error)

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.engine;

parcelable StockInfo;
```

### StockInfoObserver.aidl (Error!)

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.engine;

interface StockInfoObserver {

    void update(StockInfo stockInfo);
}
```

### AutoCompleteApi.aidl (Error!)

```
package org.yccheok.jstock.engine;

interface AutoCompleteApi {

    void handle(String string);
    void attachStockInfoObserver(StockInfoObserver stockInfoObserver);
}
```

However, Eclipse complains in `StockInfoObserver.aidl` (It does complain `AutoCompleteApi.aidl` too, as it cannot process `StockInfoObserver.aidl`),

**parameter stockInfo (1) unknown type StockInfo**

I tried for an hour, but still not able to find out, why in aidl, `StockInfo` is not being recognized although I had

1. Provided `StockInfo.aidl`
2. Provided `StockInfo.java`

Any idea?

Here are the complete errors.

[image]

Note, `AutoCompleteApi.aidl` is very much dependent on `StockInfoObserver.aidl`. That's why you will see the error.

I share the entire project for your reference purpose : https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k5pe75jolv5mtq/jstock-android.zip

Comment: probably due to another error prevent the code generation to happen. what are the other errors we see on your screenshot ?

Comment: you need first to implement handle(String) in autocompleservice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Android documentation `You must include an import statement for each additional type not listed above, even if they are defined in the same package as your interface`

Try to add this line to `StockInfoObserver.aidl`

```
import org.yccheok.jstock.engine.StockInfo;
```

Comment: You suggestion works pretty well. After adding import, seems that I need to put in/out/inout for StockInfo parameter. My activity is going to implement StockInfoObserver.Stub, and it is going to receive StockInfo from AutoCompleteService. The activity will perform readonly operation on received StockInfo. May I know, should I use in, out, or inout for the above case?

Comment: You should use `in` in your case