# AIDL passing object parameter

Tags: java, android, aidl

im currently stuck at using Object type for the AIDL.

**SongItem.java**

```
public class SongItem implements Parcelable{

}
```

**SongItem.aidl**

```
// SongItem.aidl
package com.example.krot.musicplayer;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements
parcelable SongItem;
```

**MyAIDL.aidl**

```
 interface IPlaybackAction {

     void setSongList(in List<SongItem> item);
 }
```

Everytime i rebuild the project it keeps saying that

> Error:aidl E 03-07 17:18:19 14651 1413571 type_namespace.cpp:129]  unknown type

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263005/aidl-unable-to-find-the-definition-of-a-parcelable-class

Comment: @Amir: I do as the link guided but another bug appeared: In the generated class IPlaybackAction.java (when rebuild): cannot find symbol class SongItem

public void setSongList(java.util.List<com.example.krot.musicplayer.SongItem> item) throws android.os.RemoteException;

Comment: are all package name the same com.example.krot.musicplayer in all your classes. It seems either this or some variable you havent defined.

Comment: You really need to put more details like full java classes.

Comment: Yeah i have two packages: 1 in java folder and 1 in aidl folder and they have the same name com.example.krot.musicplayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package for the `SongItem` class must match exactly between the Java and the AIDL, and the `MyAIDL.aidl` file must import the class (which is why you have the `SongItem.aidl` file which declares the class as `parcelable`.

Add this to the top of `MyAIDL.aidl`:

```
import com.example.krot.musicplayer.model.SongItem;
```

From the package structure image provided in the deleted answer, I can see `SongItem.java` is in a different package than what is in the AIDL.  Move your `SongItem.aidl` file to be in the directory `src/main/aidl/com/example/krot/musicplayer/model` and update the package declaration at the top of that file to be `com.example.krot.musicplayer.model`.

Comment: I also did that, but still not working, still this error: 
public void setSongList(java.util.List<com.example.krot.musicplayer.SongItem> item) throws android.os.RemoteException;

It did not regconize SongItem

Comment: Please provide the exact build log

Comment: 1. `Error:(363, 68) error: cannot find symbol class SongItem` . 
2. `Error:(319, 78) error: cannot find symbol class SongItem` . 
3. `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details`

Comment: Looks like something is off with the Java vs AIDL files. Could be package name, tree layout, etc. Can you make a list with a small project to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I also created a new project, and the same bug still appeared. Do two packages (**1 in java folder, 1 in aidl folder**) must have the same name? In my current project is: `com.example.krot.musicplayer`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138924/android-aidl-compile-error-couldnt-find-import-for-class/27408433 . <---- This is exactly the same issue with me, but i don't understand his verified answer

Comment: @Krot that other answer is for someone who is building their own custom service interface as part of the AOSP build, they are not using Android Studio.

Comment: Can you post a gist of your new simpler project exhibiting the same problem?

Comment: Just looked at the deleted additional data you originally posted which had the screen cap.  Your `SongItem` java object is in a different  package than the AIDL.  It is in `com.example.krot.musicplayer.model`.  I'll revise my answer above.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely right, i have to put either the **SongItem.aidl** and my **SongItem.java** in the same package. If i have my SongItem.java inside the package **com.example.krot.musicplayer.model** then i have to put my **SongItem.aidl** in the package **com.example.krot.musicplayer.model** (of course inside the aidl folder). Thank you so much, i solved my problem.